# windows phone 8 ShareMediaTask exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

am trying to share an image with ShareMediaTask.

all things works except after reaching the share app my app crashes with application unhand led exception

```
using (Stream current = await svfile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var picture = lib.SavePicture("share", current);
            ShareMediaTask task = new ShareMediaTask();


            task.FilePath = picture.GetPath();

            task.Show();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("yessss");
        }
```

its the same with mail also after reaching selection view of mail app crashes in background .

Comment: Can you provide description of Exception?

Comment: Type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that Type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Save image to media library
//toShare is the stream source. 
//Don't use using statement to get stream

MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
var picture = library.SavePicture("Memefy_Photo", toShare);

//Open ShareMediaTask
var task = new ShareMediaTask();
task.FilePath = picture.GetPath();
task.Show();
```